# How to check for cycles in a graph?

Tags: c, graph, cycle, cs50

My code works fine but fails check50 test for skipping pairs when creating cycles. The logic I use to check for cycles is that before creating an edge from winner to loser I go back the edges from the winner and check if it ever reaches the loser. If it does, it means it'll create a cycle so the edge is skipped but It doesn't work. My logic could be wrong too, if so let me know. Here's my code-

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);
bool check_cycle(int n, int m);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i], name) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < candidate_count - i; j++)
        {
            preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[i + j]]++;
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = i;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = j;
                pair_count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    pair k;
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < pair_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] < preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser])
            {
                //memcpy
                k = pairs[i];
                pairs[i] = pairs[j];
                pairs[j] = k;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        if (!check_cycle(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser))
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        bool source = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (locked[j][i] == true)
            {
                source = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (source == true)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
        }
    }

    return;
}

//checking for cycle
bool check_cycle(int n, int m)
{
    if (locked[m][n] == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (locked[i][n] == true)
        {
            check_cycle(i, m);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced there's enough information in the question yet.  It certainly isn't an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  I think maybe your cycle checking only looks for cycles of length 2 (there and back), rather than cycles involving multiple steps.  So, if you have nodes A->B->C and A->D and add C->D, maybe it doesn't detect that properly (and I'm not sure about the example).  I could be barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 2):

You're just reversing the direction of the cycle. I've used the same logic as you and it works:
 1. See if the current loser locks onto the current winner;
 2. If it does, return true;
 3. Else, see if anyone else locks onto the current winner;
 4. Recursively call the cycle checker, to see if the current loser locks onto 'i'. Now careful with this step, because you must pass the values to the function so the base case checker does [loser][i], not [i][loser], since the base case checks whether the initial LOSER locked onto the winner. And remember to return. Here's the code I used, works fine.

```
//Can_reach recursive auxiliary function: returns true if a can reach b.
//a = initial winner, b = initial loser
bool loopcheck(int a, int b)
{
    if (locked[b][a] == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (locked[i][a] == true)
            {
            return loopcheck(i, b);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think some of the previous answers gave the right answer.

1. For `n` candidates, there exists the `ith` candidate that no
   arrow pointing to her or him if and only if the ith column of the
   "locked" table is all false. In such a situation, no circle (a
   circle with n nodes) can be drawn if the ith column must be a node.
2. However, this doesn't guarantee that there are no other smaller circles. If we make the "locked" table one-size smaller (i.e. remove
   the `nth` candidate, now we will have a `(n-1) *(n-1)` "locked"
   table. Like what we did in `step(1)`, we can make sure that a circle of `n-1` nodes is also impossible. By repeating this processing, no circle (any size) is possible.
3. We can check it by using recursion.

If you don't check whether a smaller circle is possible: you will have an error like this:

> lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle
>       lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs

Here is the code:

```
bool is_circle (bool locked_array[MAX][MAX], int candi_count)
{
    //check the basic case
    //if there is only one node of course it doesn't form a circle
    if (candi_count == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //recursively check whether the smaller locked_array with n-1 candidate form a circle
    //if the smaller one have a circle
    //this mean a middle pair create a circle if added into the "locked" table
    if (!is_circle(locked_array, candi_count - 1))
    {
        //if the one-size smaller "locked" table doesn't have a circle
        //check whether adding a new candidate forms a circle

        //if there is a column that is all false's after adding a new candidate
        //then it must not introduce a circle in this step
        for (int j = 0; j < candi_count; j++)
        {
            //a indicator variable for check whether a column has a true value;
            bool true_in_column = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < candi_count; i++)
            {
                if (locked_array[i][j] == true)
                {
                    true_in_column = true;
                }
            }

            //if there is a column doesn't have a true value then not circle is create at this step
            if (true_in_column == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //if we cannot find such a column then the graph represented by current locked array
        //must have a circle
        return true;

    }

    //the smaller "locked" table forms a circle
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging the previous answers and explaining why you don't think they work. That's a good practice when answering old questions, and is much appreciated—especially for a first post. I appreciate your contribution to the community!

Answer (score 0):

`if (locked[i][n] == true)` then this "winner" (`n`) is a "loser" in another locked pair and therefore will create a cycle. IMO that's all the info you need to decide whether to lock this pair in `lock_pairs` function.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `if (locked[i][n] == true)`, in case `check_cycle(i, m)` returns true, you should also return true in check_cycle(n, m) so that the function works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this non-recursive version. Before locking pair, search for a loser to be a winner in some locked node, if there is some - skip it.

```
//set first locked pair
if(pair_count > 0)
{
    locked[pairs[0].winner][pairs[0].loser] = true;
}

for (int i = 1; i < pair_count; i++)
{
    bool cycle = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < pair_count; j++){
        if(locked[pairs[i].loser][j])
        {
            cycle = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    //check if adding this node will create a cycle
    if(!cycle)
    {
        locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `check_cycle (i, m)` in `if (locked[i][n] == true)` is returning inconsistent values

here is a code to fix that

```
bool check_cycle(int n, int m)
{
    if (locked[m][n] == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (locked[i][n] == true)
        {
            if (check_cycle(i, m))
            {
                return true;   
            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Set all the edges in graph
for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
{
    locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
}
//Check if there is a cycle remove the edges that make a cycle
for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < pair_count; j++)
    {
        if (pairs[i].winner == pairs[j].loser)
        {
            locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call this function from your lock_pairs function with (loser, winner) as arguments to check whether the loser has any connections that can trace back to the winner.

To simplify if you want to check you can make a connection a -> b then simply call if(!circle(b,a) { }. This results as true if the link will return in a closed cycle, and false if not. We essentially enter a recursive mode while passing on the n (the destination to be checked) and i ( the id we want to keep following)

```
    bool circle(int i, int n)
{
    bool b = false;
    if (i != n) // stop when the cycle results in a closed loop
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (locked[i][j] == true)
            {  
                b = circle(j, n); // Call again to follow the link from j
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        b = true; // 
    }
    return b;
}
```